# multiplication table side by side in full format

Tags: .net

Am a newbie trying to print multiplication table in below format.
I am unable to neatly output the table for numbers upto 10 or above. I have written for numbers upto 5. But failed to place the tables for 6 and above below the current output. Can somebody help me with how to print for eg from 6 to 10 below the table I have created

[image: This is the output I have created for numbers upto 5. I need the same format for numbers upto 10 or more.]

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} * {1} = {2} \t", j, i, i * j);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is right align your variables to a fixed width. You can do something like this:

```
static string RightNumber(int i)
{
    return i.ToString().PadLeft(3);
}
```

Then your `Console.Write` line would be:

```
Console.Write("{0} * {1} = {2} \t", RightNumber(j), RightNumber(i), RightNumber(i * j));
```

What that will do is make all of the numbers take up three spaces in a line. So instead of "3", it will be "  3". You can change the variable in the `PadLeft` method if you only want 2 (or 4, etc), but I assumed that you will be going up to 10 * 10 in your lists.

Comment: @krillar HI  thanks for explaining to me about padleft. Unfortunately it doesnot solve the issue. The problem is due to limitations in o/p screen size. I want the coloums for numbers above 6 to be printed below the current output(ie upto 5). With the current code,  if we increase the j value the second row will have 6*1 =6  7*1 =7 ....etc instead of 1*2 =2 2*2=4  3*2=6